# Add a popup modal to vuetify vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to add a popup-modal to a table in vuetify vue.js but it always ends up getting the value of the first item.

The problem arises on the **4th** `<td>` where I am trying to implement a pop-up modal.

It keeps getting the first element of the list only. I feel like it is a very easy fix.. it is the **4th** `<td>` just to save you time.

***Vue Template:***

```
<script>
        var model =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
</script>



<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn flat color="purple" href="/Home">Home</v-btn>
                    <v-btn flat color="purple">Inventory</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>

                <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            </v-card-title>

        </v-card>


        <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
            <v-layout>
                <v-flex xs8>

                    <v-card>

                        <v-card-title>
                            Un Added Lab Equipment
                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                            <v-text-field v-model="search"
                                          append-icon="search"
                                          label="Search"
                                          single-line
                                          hide-details></v-text-field>
                        </v-card-title>
                        <v-data-table :headers="Headers"
                                      :items="items"
                                      :search="search"
                                      item-key="equipment"
                                      hide-actions
                                      expand
                                      class="elevation-1">
                            <template slot="items" scope="props">
                                <td class="text-xs">{{ props.item.equipment }}</td>
                                <td class="text-xs">{{ props.item.location }}</td>
                                <td class="text-xs">{{ props.item.qty }}  </td>
                                <td>
                                    @*<a v-bind:href="props.item.pictureUrl">
                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" style="color: rgb(159, 212, 172);"></i></a>*@
                                    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" lazy absolute>
                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" style="color: rgb(159, 212, 172);" slot="activator"></i>
                                        <v-card>
                                            <v-card-title class="justify-center">
                                                <p class="headline">More Info  for '{{ props.item.equipment }}'</p>
                                            </v-card-title>
                                            <v-card-text>
                                                @*<v-img src="{{props.item.pictureUrl}}"
                                                    aspect-ratio="2.75"></v-img>*@ {{props.item.location}}
                                            </v-card-text>
                                            <v-card-actions>
                                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                                <v-btn class="blue--text darken-1" flat="flat" v-on:click.native="dialog = false">No</v-btn>
                                                <v-btn class="blue--text darken-1" flat="flat" v-on:click.native="deleteRow(props.item)">Yes</v-btn>
                                            </v-card-actions>
                                        </v-card>
                                    </v-dialog>

                                </td>
                                <td class="text-xs">
                                    <button v-on:click="decrement(props.item.id)" :disabled="disabled == props.item.id ? true : false">
                                        <v-icon color="pink">remove</v-icon>
                                    </button>
                                    <button v-on:click="increment(props.item.id)" id="incrementButton" :disabled="disabled == props.item.id + '2' ? true : false">
                                        <v-icon color="green">add</v-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </td>


                            </template>
                        </v-data-table>
                    </v-card>
                </v-flex>

            </v-layout>
            <br />




        </v-container>


</div>

***Vue App:***
```

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        disabled: "",
        searchAdded: '',
        message: 'omae wa moo shindeiruu',
        dialog: false,
        notifications: false,
        sound: true,
        test: true,
        widgets: false,
        search: '',
        Headers: [
            { text: 'Equipment', value: 'equipment' },
            { text: 'Location', value: 'location' },
            { text: 'Qty', value: 'qty' },
            { text: 'MoreInfo', value: 'pictureUrl',  sortable: false, disabled: true },
            { text: 'Add or Remove', value: 'addo', sortable: false, disabled: true }
        ],
        HeadersAdded: [
            { text: 'Equipment', value: 'itemName' },
            { text: 'Location', value: 'location' },
            { text: 'Qty', value: 'quantity' },
            { text: 'Add or Remove', value: 'addo', sortable: false, disabled: true }
        ],
        items: [{ equipment: "beaker", location: 'Room 3535 drawer 21', qty: 21, id: '07f37f', pictureUrl: 'https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2500x2500/Photographers_Formulary_09_0095_Glass_Beaker_600ml_231378.jpg' },
            { equipment: "ruler", location: 'Room 3535 drawer 10', qty: 7, id: '08f312', pictureUrl: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qUVuXt2AL.jpg' },
            { equipment: "flask", location: 'Room 2121 drawer 22', qty: 6, id: '09f37d', pictureUrl: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/316GJIEdJxL._SY445_.jpg' },
            { equipment: "vernier-caliber", location: 'Room 4125 drawer 21', qty: 12, id: '07g3hf', pictureUrl: 'https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/2ZUF3_AS01?$mdmain$' }
                ],
        itemsAdded: []
    }

}
```

})

Comment: Where is `model` coming from? That is not an accepted Vue property.

Comment: im using vuetify to load the table and model. I hope this is what you are asking about?

Comment: I am referring to the `model` property.  This does not exist in Vue. `new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  model: model,` Furthermore, you reference this `model` prop within your Vue object - where is this data coming from? What is `model`? Can you supply the code for it?

Comment: oohhh I am using razor mvc for asp.net so I am passing in a model and having it JSON encoded so I can manipulate it using vue.js This is what I am doing


<script>
        var model =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
</script>

Comment: And thats working? Do you have a sample of the JSON data that I can use to test with?

Comment: I am Sorry for the late reply yes that is working..

Comment: I have added how my items look when I pass it through the model. That is how it looks when I pass my model through from my controller

Comment: I must be missing something because I do not see any `v-for` in your code.

Comment: Also, the data you supplied goes in `items: []` but where does `model: model` come from? This is NOT an allowed property in Vue.........can you please supply the code you are using...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HnzCXv9.png

Comment: Hey I just made it possible so you would not need to have model anymore, so you do not need to  worry about it. since it seems stressfull.

Comment: I just need help with the modal popup. it would only read the first element. You do not have to worry about the increment and decrement button.  with the plus and minus sign. I have it working on my full code

Comment: I did not add my whole code because it might be hard to read

Comment: but it should work if you just copy and paste now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by changing the `v-model` for the `v-dialog` on each item..

***Code Snippet is below, and I have created a [CodePen Mirror here](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/xNjBaj?editors=1010) as well.***

It now sets the dialog open/close property for each specific item in the items list:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog[props.item.equipment]"...
```

The activator slot now looks like this:

```
...@click.stop="$set(dialog, props.item.equipment, true)" slot="activator"...
```

..and the "close button" for the `v-dialog` had to also be modified to:

```
...@click.stop="$set(dialog, props.item.equipment, false)"...
```

This means I also had to change `dialog` in your `data()` props to be an object:

```
data() {
  return {
    ...
    dialog: {},
    ...
  }
}
```

---

***CODE SNIPPET:***

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      disabled: "",
      searchAdded: "",
      message: "omae wa moo shindeiruu",
      dialog: {},
      notifications: false,
      sound: true,
      test: true,
      widgets: false,
      search: "",
      Headers: [
        { text: "Equipment", value: "equipment" },
        { text: "Location", value: "location" },
        { text: "Qty", value: "qty" },
        {
          text: "MoreInfo",
          value: "pictureUrl",
          sortable: false,
          disabled: false
        },
        {
          text: "Add or Remove",
          value: "addo",
          sortable: false,
          disabled: true
        }
      ],
      HeadersAdded: [
        { text: "Equipment", value: "itemName" },
        { text: "Location", value: "location" },
        { text: "Qty", value: "quantity" },
        {
          text: "Add or Remove",
          value: "addo",
          sortable: false,
          disabled: true
        }
      ],
      items: [
        {
          equipment: "beaker",
          location: "Room 3535 drawer 21",
          qty: 21,
          id: "07f37f",
          pictureUrl:"https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2500x2500/Photographers_Formulary_09_0095_Glass_Beaker_600ml_231378.jpg"
        },
        {
          equipment: "ruler",
          location: "Room 3535 drawer 10",
          qty: 7,
          id: "08f312",
          pictureUrl: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qUVuXt2AL.jpg"
        },
        {
          equipment: "flask",
          location: "Room 2121 drawer 22",
          qty: 6,
          id: "09f37d",
          pictureUrl: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/316GJIEdJxL._SY445_.jpg"
        },
        {
          equipment: "vernier-caliber",
          location: "Room 4125 drawer 21",
          qty: 12,
          id: "07g3hf",
          pictureUrl: "https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/2ZUF3_AS01?$mdmain$"
        }
      ],
      itemsAdded: []
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://static.fontawesome.com/css/fontawesome-app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                Un Added Lab Equipment
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-text-field v-model="search" append-icon="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details>
                </v-text-field>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-data-table :headers="Headers" :items="items" :search="search" item-key="equipment" hide-actions expand
                class="elevation-1">
                <template slot="items" scope="props">
                    <td class="text-xs">{{ props.item.equipment }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs">{{ props.item.location }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs">{{ props.item.qty }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <v-dialog v-model="dialog[props.item.equipment]" lazy absolute>
                            <v-btn flat icon color="blue lighten-2"
                                @click.stop="$set(dialog, props.item.equipment, true)" slot="activator">
                                <v-icon>info</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                            <v-card>
                                <v-card-title>
                                    <div class="headline">More Info for '{{ props.item.equipment }}'</div>
                                </v-card-title>
                                <v-card-text>
                                    <v-img :src="props.item.pictureUrl" aspect-ratio="2.75"></v-img>
                                    {{props.item.location}}
                                </v-card-text>
                                <v-card-actions>
                                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                    <v-btn class="blue--text darken-1" flat="flat"
                                        @click.stop="$set(dialog, props.item.equipment, false)">No</v-btn>
                                    <v-btn class="blue--text darken-1" flat="flat"
                                        @click.native="deleteRow(props.item)">Yes</v-btn>
                                </v-card-actions>
                            </v-card>
                        </v-dialog>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-xs">
                        <button v-on:click="decrement(props.item.id)"
                            :disabled="disabled == props.item.id ? true : false">
                            <v-icon color="pink">remove</v-icon>
                        </button>
                        <button v-on:click="increment(props.item.id)" id="incrementButton"
                            :disabled="disabled == props.item.id + '2' ? true : false">
                            <v-icon color="green">add</v-icon>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
    </v-app>
</div>
```